# Struggle to be sure about the subject of this sentence

Tags: determiners, subordinate-clauses, subjects, parsing

I have an assumption but I am not pretty sure.
Does 'no difference' is the subject of the next sentence?

If so, how can it be a subject with **no** + **difference**?

> The result was that **no difference** between base-oriented and object-oriented software could be measured over maintainability.

**EDIT**:

As @relaxing indicates that I actually want to know the subject of the subordinate clause,so we have found that!.

So again, how can it be a subject with **no** + **difference**?

Comment: *No* is a determiner (quantifier) here. The clause has basically the same structure as *Each difference could be ...*, *Every difference could be ...*, *Any difference could be ...*

Comment: The subject of the subordinate clause is *no difference between base-oriented and object-oriented software*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subclause in active voice:

- We could find no difference / a small difference/ a big difference/ a difference. - Four examples for direct objects.

In passive voice the object becomes the subject:
- No difference / a small difference / a big difference / a difference could be found.

The noun groups with "difference" are the subjects, 
It does not matter what sub-elements the word "difference" has.
You can replace all four subjects by a pronoun such as something or it:

- Something could be found.
- It could be found.

Answer (score 0):

The subject of the sentence is **The result**, the verb is **was**, and **that no difference...** is a *subordinate clause* serving as a direct object.

The subordinate clause has its own subject (**no difference...**) and verb (**be measured**.)

EDIT: *How* can "no difference" be a subject -- there are such things as *complex subjects* that can be entire noun phrases, or nouns and simple modifiers. In this case, **no + difference**, the "no" *quantifies* the amount of difference, and the subject becomes the sum meaning of both words.

Comment: Thanks I will edit my post, so apparently I am right  about 'no difference' is a subject of **the subordinate clause** but how no + difference could be a subject ?

Comment: Consider the example - "No man ever set foot on the surface of Mars till now" what do you think about this sentence? Is it okay? And what is the subject?

Comment: [not any man][s] ever set foot .... right?

Comment: The subject of that sentence is "no man". So if we can use "no + noun" as subject in this sentence, what is wrong with these kind of constructions to be the subject of a subordinate clause like you have in your original sentence?

Comment: @relaxing just a comment on naming. The subordinate clause is acting as a **subject predicative**. It is said that copular verbs (*be*, *seem*, *look like*...) don't take objects, instead what happens is that the subject predicative complements the subject.